# Import Excel Data into Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have some code that i wrote to export data from cells and it imports it into a word documents.

My two issues that i am having trouble with are as followed

1. Right now it just imports the cell data into the start of the document. What i need it to do is import the data into predefined textboxes
2. Right now i can run the code in the VBA editor and step into the code and run through it with no issues but if I assign the code to a button it errors. The problem is the box appear and there is no text in it

here is my current code

```
Sub Invoice()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\account\Desktop\Invoice.docx"

Dim strValue1 As String
Dim strValue2 As String
Dim strValue3 As String

objWord.Activate

strValue1 = Cells(Selection.Row, 2)
strValue2 = Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
strValue3 = Cells(Selection.Row, 4)
objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=strValue1
objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=strValue2
objWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=strValue3
End Sub
```

any help would be great appreciated

Cheers!
GreatSc0tt

Comment: By far the easiest way to insert text into a document is to use bookmarks.

Comment: "...but if I assign the code to a button it errors"  What error do you get, at what line?

Comment: so i figured out the button problem. It was the line 'objWord.Activate' that was causing the issue. 

I am still having problems with the text fields tho

Comment: @Cominterm do you have any resources on bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the textboxes by:

objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strValue1
objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strValue2

hope this helps!